# Breakwire alarm (squib) utilising a transformer

Tags: transformer

Following my yesterday post which was a break wire alarm based on logic gates to drive a siren for the protection of a camp site, I have decided to work on a second concept that uses completely different circuit based on a simple transformer design. Considering that the main uninvited visitors of the camp site are stray dogs and wild boars, I've decided to use squib (firecracker) as the main load simply because I've found it extremely more effective than siren, which doesn't seem to scare them anymore.

In the following circuit the primary of T1 is energised upon closure of switch 1. The role of R2 is to limit the current coming from a 9v battery. When the wire is broken by animals, the sudden collapse of primary will induce a transient in secondary, which in turn, heats up the extremely thin nichrome wire (0.02mm) of the squib. The switch 2 is a safety measure which is closed at first to bypass any transient when the circuit is powered up first and then it's opened by the operator. 
My question is regarding the transformer itself, what type of transformer would work best? My assumption is step down type with a very high number of thin wire turns at primary and a secondary with thicker and fewer turns to provide sufficient current for the squib. Please share your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: What an odd idea.... R u planning on going out and fixing the wire in the middle of the night after the first boar... or camper.. breaks the wire? Even if that is the case, the whole thing could be done very simply with a resistor, a battery, and a transistor, or better, a MOSFET.

Comment: Hi Trevor, as you know I already have a circuit which you helped to improve yesterday. This is however, came to my mind when user287001 suggested a closed loop system. I know it's odd but it's interesting if it works. The firecracker will makes an easier sounding system than a siren. As long as it wakes us up it should be good.

Comment: YOu know..if you are serious about all this you may want to think about something a bit more reliable that doesn't need to be reset / have someone walk the perimeter to find the break, and resets itself.....

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you need to invert your architecture and get rid of the transformer altogether.
Perhaps something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5jBpc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this you'd have 90 uA loop current and plenty of energy to fire the squib even with only a small 9 V battery. I've included both your 'safety' switch and a loop test switch so you know that the break loop is ok before you toggle the safety.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the this, I have two questions. Can the value of R1 be further increased to lower the power consumption? and how is the reliability of mosfet vs e.g BJT against noises ?

Comment: Ya u need a filter cap across D1 @JackCreasy. That wire is one huge antenna. See yesterdays question ..

Comment: Yeah Trevor maybe combining your famous filter circuit with this circuit ?

Comment: From yesterday http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/291510/suggestions-to-filter-rf-from-a-long-wire-connected-to-a-logic-gate#291523

Comment: @Baphomet. It absolutely fascinates me that folks still persevere with logic gates for projects such as this. It costs over a dollar to buy 3 * 4011's but $0.56 for an ATTiny20 or $0.58 for a PIC16F54 with about the same number of I/O pins. You don't need to be a champion programmer to code you alarm logic, but I'm sure the ease of design and maintenance make them much better choices for these small projects. Once you make the transition to a small MCU, your design splits into just two major blocks ...I/O pins ...and code. Make the move!

Comment: There is no argue that micro controllers are best choice. But, as a hobbyist I have found programming confusing. Also, i am concerned with power consumption . With CMOS logic there is almost no power consumption.

Comment: @Trevor. I don't think you need a capacitor across the gate at all. That's a power FET with a huge capacitance (approaching 1000 pF, and add to it the capacitance of the Zener diode (about 300- 400 pF). If it makes you feel safer....by all means ...but I don't think it's needed. Remember that I simply selected the devices offered by CircuitLab ....maybe there are better choices that could be a made. The zener for example could be a 1N5242 which has lower threshold current.

Comment: @JackCreasey could you please answer the two questions above? Thanks

Comment: A micro would not reduce this circuitry much @JackCreasey, if at all. You would still need a beefy driver, and the sensing circuitry and even more protection. It's basically just a switch so the MCU would add no value.

Comment: @Trevor if the micro had low power consumption and was reliable , actually wouldn't be bad alternative to the logic circuit. Consider the function of the logic circuit from yesterday. It has 60s power on delay, meantime if break wire is connected properly, the green led turns on, otherwise it won't , which indicates break wire is faulty. It also denies the power to charging delay cap. At the end of delay green led turns off. All of this can be programmed by MCU, only if it had same power consumption and reliability.

Comment: @Baphomet.. the above is NOT a logic circuit. Its simply a switch with protection. The only place you could put a micro in there would be between R1 and the Mosfet, and all it would do is say If input =1 make output =1.. so what's the point. Plus you would then have to make sure the input was suitable for the micro.... Though I agree with you in principal, is does not apply in this situation. Blindly using a micro without thinking is a mistake.

Comment: @Trevor I was comparing the MCU with my original logic design from yesterday.

Comment: Oops sorry.. I misdirected those comments, they should have been for @JackCreasey.

Comment: And yes, yesterdays circuit was more worthy.

Comment: @Trevor which of the following do you think is best against RF, EMI induced noise in the Jack circuit to avoid false trigger? BJT, Mosfet, SCR

Comment: Door B would be my choice for many reasons, most them functionality.

Comment: I will upload the completed logic gate circuit, including the filtering stage, to the yesterday post in the next hour or so. have a look and give a final verdict. Thank you

Comment: @Baphomet. I agree wholeheartedly that CMOS static logic has impressively low supply current (around 0.5 uA). But you can get a very complex processor like the ATMega328P down to under 1 uA, which beats 3 * 4011's. I'm not suggesting that the MCU is always the right solution, But for many simple battery powered projects they are hard to beat. So for your circuit from yesterday I'd suggest that the low power Arduino type environment would be better ...and for todays question the MCU is unlikely to be able to beat the cost of what has been proposed (a single FET).

Comment: @JackCreasey I agree too, but for now I do the logic circuit until I get better at programming. As I said I'll upload the final design in next hour. I'd appreciate any input and suggestion.

Comment: @ Trevor I've posted the completed circuit here in case you'r interested to see it. It works as it should on breadboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need electrical data on the squib before continuing.  In particular, you need to know how much voltage and current must be supplied to the squib for how long to set it off.

I expect the total energy required would be significantly more than what can be stored in the magnetic field of a reasonable transformer.  You're also only allowing 90 µA to flow thru the transformer.  That's going to require a very large primary inductance to store a reasonable amount of energy.

Your circuit is also very wasteful of the limited battery energy because the energy has to be maintained in the transformer core all the time, and most of the time it won't be used.  It would be much better to use a transistor to invert the current on/off in the loop.  The squib would be actively driven directly from the battery whenever the loop is opened.

Again though, start with the squib specs.  Making a circuit to drive it when a connection is opened should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , the squib seems to be sensitive. I charged a 100uf cap to 9v and it set it off. I haven't tried lower value caps. If I increase the resistor value to 1m, would that improve energy consumption? regarding the transistor, could you please show the schematic? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simpler to do something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fndOCY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The gate is too exposed on this.

Comment: @JackCreasey, yup, you took it a lot further too. I like :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a hobbyist but here's my view on the matter:

Using a transformer to match up to the very low impedance of your squib may seem like a good idea (and it is), but ignoring the details of your primary circuit for a moment (it's not relevant to me for now) the problem will be in transferring sufficient energy to guarantee an all-fire specification for your squib.

You've provided zero specifications for the squib. Estes provides very clear all-fire specifications for their rocket engine squibs, by comparison. You have to deliver a certain number of Joules (about \$\frac{1}{2}\:\ J\$) within a certain period of time (\$50\:\textrm{ms}\$) in order to meet their all-fire specification. Their specification is actually rather difficult to meet with a transformer arranged as you have it.

Review [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/289258/capacitive-current-leads-inductive-lags-but-how-does-this-translate-to-voltage/289305#289305) I provided earlier regarding the basic energy equations for capacitors and inductors.

A capacitor's energy is \$\frac{1}{2} C V^2\$ and is stored as lines of electric force in vacuum regardless of the dielectric itself (which actually acts to counter the electric force in dielectrics), but it's easiest to imagine that once you've selected your capacitor the energy present is a matter of how much charge stored on it. Matching up the capacitor to a particular squib would be about meeting the specification I mentioned earlier. You could store a lot of energy on a super-cap, for example, with very low voltage. But it wouldn't deliver the required energy in the required time since the voltage present would be too low to induce enough current in a short enough time. Most of the energy would stay on the capacitor. So the selection of the capacitor depends upon the load. The pairing must be arranged to meet the all-fire specification.

An inductor's (transformer here) energy is \$\frac{1}{2} L I^2\$ and is stored as lines of magnetic force in vacuum space regardless of the core material used. (In your case, you may want a gapped core.) But again, it is easiest to imagine that once you've selected your inductor/transformer, the energy present is a matter of Webers (volt-seconds, and the equivalent of charge on capacitors.) Again, the selection of the inductor/transformer depends upon the load and the pairing must be arranged to meet the all-fire specification.

For inductors/transformers this is often more of a problem. You may have noticed that the volume of a capacitor (for a given manufacturing technology) is proportional to the energy it can store. The same is true for inductors/transformers.

If you had a specification (you don't, yet), it might be possible to compute the required core volume needed to store the energy you want held there. (You might read [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/273008/turns-for-saturating-a-toroid-at-a-particular-frequency/273022#273022) from me which is one place where I discussed core volumes.) But that can't be done just yet because you don't have a specification. And I suspect you will be disappointed at the sheer size required, once you are able to provide an accurate specification (considering that you are imagining a single pulse here.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The squibs I am using are different from commercial type. They are ex military. They have much thiner nichrome wire, 0.02mm thickness and about 2-3mm long. I fired one with 100uf cap charged to 9v. They make a good bang for scaring animals. I haven't tried lower value caps. I know the commercial variety use much thicker wire.

Comment: I think the specs are : 22uF, 12v. I also measured the resistance, it was 6 ohm.

Comment: @Baphomet Thanks! That's a lot more resistance than the Estes squibs, by the way.

Comment: yes because it's much thinner and requires less energy.

Comment: @Baphomet Do you have any information about how long it takes to actually fire? Is it on the order of 50 ms? Hmm. Never mind. You gave me a capacitor. That's good enough. I can work it out. About \$1.6\:\textrm{mJ}\$ and \$\tau=132\:\mu\textrm{s}\$. \$5\tau\$ would be more than long enough.

Comment: @Baphomet Your circuit shows \$C_4=300\:\mu\textrm{F}\$. So that, even with the lower voltage, suggests more energy into the squib in the circuit you posted. Doesn't mean it's required. Just noting the difference. In any case, looks like you already have some solutions which are in some ways better than going with an inductor or transformer. The huge advantage of an inductor in a case like this is that you can design things so that there is no possibility of static charges to any circuit node accidentally causing a misfire. For max safety that way, I'd probably avoid mosfets.

Comment: Yeah I chose 300uF to be on the safe side. Actually, I might change to 150uF for lower leakage. I am also using BJT as they are more reliable than mosfets as you said. The transformer just was an idea that came to my mind and I thought I could build up on that as a side project. What do you think of the logic circuit I posted?

Comment: @Baphomet I worked on an Estes squib ignitor that worked from a 3V lithium button battery (drawing only \$500\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and taking about 5-6 minutes to become fully ready to deliver a pulse) and used an inductor *and* a xenon flash lamp for absolute safety. I found the problem to be non-trivial, though. The Estes squibs require more than 100X the energy you seem to need. So you are in a better situation. By the way, where do you get those squibs?

Comment: It's funny, I just noticed that I had over 60m of the same diameter nichrome wire. I don't even know when and where I got that. It's so thin that hard to see. The size is 52AWG. The squibs are from a friend who retired in russian army. I am from georgia.

Comment: @Baphomet Ah. The Estes squibs also include a small bit of pyro material on them, as well (and some laquer to protect the end from moisture and so on.) The xenon flash lamp is very hard to accidentally trigger and it's timing is quite precise, so I could trigger several at one time for multi-engine cases. I had to custom-design and custom-build the inductor for it, which is what got me into that whole process years ago.

Comment: There is no indication that BJT's are more reliable than FETs (in circuit) that I know off. Can either one of you point to any documentation showing there are less reliable?

Comment: @JackCreasey Just to be clear, that wasn't my comment. In my case I used a custom transformer and xenon flash lamp for triggering precision and security. I think the question you are asking depends upon surrounding circumstances and, in any case, should be directed at Baphomet. I didn't make the comment and don't intend on defending it, regardless of how I might feel about it (as yet, unstated here.)

Comment: @ jonk the jack's comment was directed at my question that I asked from Trevor regarding the probability of false trigger of different transistors. If I remember correctly, I read somewhere that mosfets due to high input impedance are more susceptible to ESD and false triggering. Offcourse, I don't believe everything I read.

Comment: @Baphomet The human body can easily provide the necessary charge to a mosfet gate, if the circuit allows it. But that can be handled. (A BJT doesn't have the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the revised version of the logic circuit from yeserday including filtering components. I have also modified the load so it's using squib (firecracker) rather than buzzer. With extra safety clamping circuit. It works like a charm on breadboard.

[image]

Comment: Just a few thoughts: Q1 off state Collector current may exceed current through R2. Q1 turned off you can exceed V(be) breakdown (unlikely to damage Q1,but will rapidly charge C1). C4 charge state limited by 2 * 2N6427 off state Collector current (about 1-2 uA combined), likely maximum 7 - 8 V on C4. TVS1 leakage can exceed current through R4 - R8. Your 'loop ok' condition has the voltage on C2 very close to the VT+ threshold of about 6 V. While the TVS leakage may mean you never see an open loop, if it is working it is too close to the limits.

Comment: Ok, first about Q1, I guess reducing R2 to 4.7m help. Or should I change the type of transistor? Also I should choose a transistor with high V(be) breakdown. I'll change Q5 to a NPN to help C4 develop more voltage. The TVS that i am using has 1uA leakage.  Vishay SA12A-E3/54. Is that high?  If you have any solution to above problems please share. Thanks

Comment: Also TVS is 12v.

Comment: Extreme low current design is almost as much art form as engineering. I hate to say that given the application you are designing for that a small MCU would appear a better solution and would get you to very long battery life ...approaching the self discharge rate. And... Yes 1 uA of leakage in any component is high for the resistor values you have.

Comment: @JackCreasey Could you explain why the voltage on c2 is 6v?

Comment: I mean close to 6v.

Comment: Oh of course , the 1uA leakage of TVS makes it like a 9m resistor which basically makes a voltage divider with R4. should I get rid of TVS or decrease R4 to 2m? Also, same situation with Q1 and R2. The value of R2 needs to be decreased considerably to 2m

Comment: Leakage current can't readily be expressed as an equivalent resistor value. It's a current limit more like a constant current, so in your divider (R4/R8) with the two 3.3 M resistors the maximum current (VCC - 3diode_drops / 6.6M Ohm) perhaps around (7.v/6.6^6) --> 1.2 uA. This is right about the same value as the TVS leakage. So given that the leakage current may have a low voltage dependency the lower end of R8 may be about 1V, VCC will be about 8 V so you have the center point of R4/R8 at about 4.5 V or above (depending on the voltage that appears across the TVS leakage).

Comment: I'd simply get rid of R8 to solve the potential problems.

Comment: @JackCreasey the previous design didn't have R8, but as some people pointed it out in the previous post, connecting the long wire (60ft) without a large resistance directly to the gate isn't a good idea. What about reducing the R4 and R8 each to 1M? Would that eliminate the problem?

Comment: I'd suggest R8=10k and R4=1M. This would swamp any leakages and still be low supply current. The CD4000 series have input protection diodes and only need a small value series resistor: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-77.pdf

Comment: Ok, I'll change the resistor values. On the subject of micro-controllers, which of them would be the best candidate for this application? The main requirements are low power, ruggedness and reliability.

Comment: @JackCreasey I have found a great article on how to reduce the power of Arduino mini pro (ATmega328) down to uA levels. http://www.home-automation-community.com/arduino-low-power-how-to-run-atmega328p-for-a-year-on-coin-cell-battery/

Comment: IMO you can do no better than start with the Arduino/AVR processors. I use Arduino Nano's as just my basic starting point in any project and ATMega328P's most of the time, though I also use ATMega8L and ATTiny2313 (I bought in bulk which commits me to using these up). If you are just starting out I'd recommend you stay with the ATMega328P/ATTiny85 and just use Nano's or Pro Mini's or the ATTiny85 based Digisparks as project components. The development environment is free and fully debugged and a breeze to use ...what's not to like.

Comment: @JackCreasey I've ordered arduino uno (ATMega328) and I am going to use at as a learning platform to get started with the programming. I'll dedicate the pro version for the alarm project as it's small and the hardware can be modified for low power. Also, it support sleep mode as it says in the posted link. My question is  can it function for the intended purpose while in the sleep mode?